# Why am I not able to display strings with the following code?

Tags: c, string

If I put an "&" in the printf, it will at-least print the names of the countries and it will crash. Otherwise, it crashes immediately. My guess is, there is something wrong with the for loop. Let me know, if I am wrong.

```
 //Implementation file//
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>
 struct list
 {
     char *item;
     int length;
 };
 typedef struct list LIST; //aliasing the structure//
 LIST *create()      //constrcutor//
 {
     LIST *L = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof (LIST));
     L->length=0;
     return L;
 }
 void insert(LIST* L, char *newitem)
 {
     L->item=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
     strcpy(L->item, newitem);
     (L->length)++;
 }
 void display(LIST *L)
 {
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<(L->length);i++)
     {
         printf("Elements are: %s\n", L->item[i]);

     }
 }
 int main ()
 {
     LIST *L;
     L=create();
     insert(L, "America");
     insert(L, "Brazil");
     display(L);
     free(L->item);
     free(L);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Your list code is utterly broken. On `insert` you only allocate space for one character when you should be allocating enough for the length of `newitem`. Also, on every call to `insert` you overwrite the head of the list (losing track of previous items) instead of actually appending. In `display` you try to print each element by array-indexing into the string in the head item, which simply makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a gigantic error in your code: **when inserting new elements you're supposed to create a new list element** and initialize it..

With the function

```
 void insert(LIST* L, char *newitem)
 {
     L->item=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
     strcpy(L->item, newitem);
     (L->length)++;
 }
```

called like this:

```
 insert(L, "America");
 insert(L, "Brazil");
```

you're always writing the same element for *length* and allocating **new memory** (without even using/storing a pointer to the old allocated one.. which is lost!).

You should rather do something like:

```
//Implementation file//
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>
 struct list
 {
     char *item;
     struct list* next;
 };
 typedef struct list LIST; //aliasing the structure//
 LIST *create()      //constrcutor//
 {
     LIST *L = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof (LIST));
     L->next = 0;
     return L;
 }
 LIST* insert(LIST* L, char *newitem)
 {
     L->item=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(newitem));
     strcpy(L->item, newitem);
     LIST *newL = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof (LIST));
     newL->next = 0;
     L->next = newL;
     return newL;
 }
 void display(LIST *L)
 {
     int i;
     for(i=0; L->next != 0;L = L->next) // Assumes there's at least 1 item
     {
         printf("Elements are: %s\n", L->item);
     }
 }
 int main ()
 {
     LIST *startElement;
     startElement=create();
     LIST *lastElement = insert(startElement, "America");
     lastElement = insert(lastElement, "Brazil");
     display(startElement);
     // Free all memory.. exercise :)
     return 0;
 }
```

Try it out interactively: http://ideone.com/n8tRtv

Otherwise the purpose of linked lists would be entirely defeated.. who wants a list which loses the previous elements when you insert new ones?

Notice that the above code

1. Doesn't free memory
2. Always assumes there's at least an item in the list

If you want a complete code, well.. fix it. If you understand how it works it should be rather feasible to fix it entirely. Good luck!

Comment: Nothing in OP implies a linked list.

Comment: Aside from the "list" name, the "item" subfield and the "insertElement" function you mean?

Comment: And what implies links?

Comment: I don't know if this is what OP wanted, of course. But it seemed logical to me, I'm sorry if that's not what he wanted but since the insertElement function, the pointer-like style and all the names pointed in that direction, I assumed it could be better to point him out his errors with linked lists rather than fixing a problem which is like the tip of an iceberg in that case

Comment: It smells like linked-list CS homework to me, for sure.

Answer (score 3):

```
L->item=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
strcpy(L->item, newitem);
```

You are allocating only one byte, but you try to copy a whole string into `L->item`, resulting in undefined behaviour. This should be:

```
L->item=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(newitem)+1));
strcpy(L->item, newitem);
```

You are also calling the function `insert` twice, which will allocate new memory for `L->item` and loose the pointer to the previous allocated space -> Memory leak. You should add list elements instead of overwriting the first one all the time, see @DavidKernin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following modification of your code will allow you to insert strings and print them. Since that is what you asked for, that is what you shall get. If you had some sort of specific data structure in mind (perhaps a linked list etc.) when coding this up, please specify.

```
struct list
{
    char **item;
    int length;
};
```

struct list now holds an array of pointers to char *.

```
LIST *create()
{
    LIST *L = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof (LIST));
    L->item = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    L->length=0;
    return L;
}
```

This would be the proper way to malloc for your list.

```
void insert(LIST* L, char *newitem)
{
    L->item[L->length] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));    
    strcpy(L->item[L->length++], newitem);
}
```

To insert you malloc for a new char pointer, which is placed in the end of your array of char pointers. The inserted string is copied and length is incremented.

And don't forget to free()!

Comment: With your code, I was able to get the results I wanted. I am very new to data structure so am not sure if I framed the question wrong. However, what I wanted was to be able to manipulate the data like sort the name of country and delete a country name and stuff like that. I am able to do all the manipulation in a regular array. I don't know why i am not able to do it in strings. Anyway, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The specifier in the `printf` statement is incorrect.  You are using `%s` which expects a `char*` but you are passing a `char`.  As a result the `printf` implementation is treating the character value as an address and promptly running off into invalid memory and crashing

To fix this you need to switch to using `%c`

```
printf("Elements are: %c\n", L->item[i]);
```

Note that this will cause every `char` to be printed out on a different line.  Most likely you want something like the following

```
printf("Elements are: %s\n", L->item[i]);
int i;
for(i=0;i<(L->length);i++)
{
  printf("%c", L->item[i]);

}
printf("\n");
```

Note that if your intent is to have the `item` member be a null terminated `char*` then the simplest fix is to do the following

```
printf("Elements are: %s\n", L->item);
```

Comment: I want to print string, not a character. How do I do that? Any other changes I need to make?

Comment: @anansharm to print a `char*` you need a null terminated `char*` value.  Given that you have a length associated with the `char*` i assumed it was not null terminated hence I opted for printing out individual characters

Comment: -1, much simpler would be to do `printf("%s", L->item);`

Comment: A `char*` is not a string; a `char*` may point to a string. `"%s"` expects a `char*` argument, and requires it to point to a string. (A string is null-terminated by definition.)

Comment: What I wanted to do was item[0] = America, item[1] = Brazil etc. I am trying to imagine how to achieve that with your solution.

Comment: @AndrewMedico i updated to include this possibility but his code doesn't guarantee its null terminated in this case.  if it's the intent then yes that would work but the presence of the length field and the OPs usage of it suggests it wasn't guaranteed to be null terminated

Answer (score 0):

```
L->item=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

is one problem in the code

Comment: And maybe u will explain to OP what is wrong there and how to fix it ?

Comment: @Roma-MT - You can take a horse to water but you cannot make it drink